# Activity is not calling back from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I have an activity that takes an "intent" to the browser, I see the page on which connect and when I return to my work I press the button to go back to my activity. The problem is that it gets stuck in the browser. Is there any solution? Thank you very much for everything and sorry for my English.
here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(/*my url*/));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh... My bad.!!!!.. I have checked my manifest file ..and I have put `NoHistory=true` on my parent actvity.

Answer (score 0):

The `Intent` you used is just to open browser. If you want to handle the result then you need to consider implementing [Custom WebView Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). So that you can do what ever you like with the browser.

Comment: i am using web browser bcz i have many operations on it.. and in web view .. it is not allowing me to do so..

Comment: I have a product webpage in which i have some operations.. i dont  want to bring anything from it..all the operations are done in that web page only.

Comment: Ok.Fine. Implementing WebView will offer all those operations. IT will look like a usual web page but the difference is in app browser which you can control.